# PhoneGap 2.3: InAppBrowser plugin not found

Tags: cordova, plugins

I upgraded PhoneGap in my iOS app to version 2.3 which now ships with InAppBrowser feature build-in.

To trigger it, I call in JavaScript:

> window.open(url, "_blank");

But that won't work (nothing happens in my app), instead I see in the logs:

> CDVPlugin class CVDInAppBrowser (pluginName: InAppBrowser) does not exist. ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin.
>
> Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["InAppBrowser1976814969","InAppBrowser","open",["http://www.google.com","_blank",null]]

So I checked my config.xml which looks good (it's definately there):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<cordova>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CVDInAppBrowser" />
    </plugins>
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="*.jquery.com" />
    <access origin="*mydomain.de" />
</cordova>
```

Comment: Hi, I've hit a similar issue - did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @JamesJ Nope, I created a whole new PhoneGap project and copied the www folder from my old project into the new one. Now it works..

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try - having the same issue with the EmailComposerWithAttachment plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here might be that you have "CVDInAppBrowser", but it should be "CDVInAppBrowser".